# Adding a new (hidden) "Delete" Context Menu item to Windows 7

Tags: windows, shell, context-menu

I would like to add a new "Delete" context menu item such that I can delete large amounts of files and folders with a single right click without using explorer because of how slow it is. I have already made such an item using the following reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\delas]
@="DeleteCMD"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\delas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\delas]
@="DeleteCMD"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\delas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
```

It uses "del and "rmdir" to delete the files and/or folders, which works fine, except that it pops up a shell window.

I would like to know three things:

1. <strike>Is there any way to change the above code such that a shell window does not pop up?</strike>
2. Is there any way to replace Window's built in context menu "Delete" function with the above code?
3. Is this the best way to go about this?

**Update:**

I figured out how to suppress the shell window by installing nircmd (make sure to add it to the windows directory first):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\delas]
@="DeleteCMD"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\delas\command]
@="nircmd.exe exec hide cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
"IsolatedCommand"="nircmd.exe exec hide cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\delas]
@="DeleteCMD"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\delas\command]
@="nircmd.exe exec hide cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
"IsolatedCommand"="nircmd.exe exec hide cmd.exe /c del /f/s/q \"%1\" > nul & rmdir /s/q \"%1\" "
```

To uninstall:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\delas]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\delas]
```

But I still need help with #2 and #3.